# Nuget Pack - Is there a way to use wildcards or variables for the Suffix?

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I'm using nuget pack to create a Nuget package from the command-line like this:

```
nuget pack -Build -Properties Configuration=Release -Suffix beta1
```

Is there any way to use a wildcard or variable in the suffix argument, so I can automatically pull in the build number or something else?

Looking to do something like this (which doesn't work):

```
nuget pack -Build -Properties Configuration=Release -Suffix beta$(buildNumber)
nuget pack -Build -Properties Configuration=Release -Suffix beta$(variableFromSomewhere)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use TFS to create a package, it supports using variable.

You could either use `nuget pack` and select `Automatic package versioning` to create packages:

[image]

Or use `Nuget custom` to specify the command:

[image]

Comment: Can this be done from a command prompt or only through VSTS/TFS?

Comment: Where are you going to locate the variables when you use command line only?

Comment: My question was about command line Nuget and you provided an answer about VSTS/TFS.